# Difference between various verifySignatures functions in Corda flow unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, kotlin, corda

What's the difference between those three methods in Corda flow unit testing?

```
ptx.verify(servicehub)
ptx.verifyRequiredSignatures()
ptx.verifySignaturesExcept(vararg allowedToBeMissed)
```

Because now I cannot use `ptx.verifySignatures()` as before and I have those three options!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**verify**

`fun verify(services: ServiceHub, checkSufficientSignatures: Boolean = true)` verifies that the transaction is valid according to the contracts of its states.

If `checkSufficientSignatures == true`, this function will also check that all the required signatures are present and valid.

**verifyRequiredSignatures**

`fun verifyRequiredSignatures()` checks that all the required signatures are present and valid, but does **not** check whether the transaction is valid according to the contracts of its states.

**verifySignaturesExcept**

`fun verifySignaturesExcept(vararg allowedToBeMissing: PublicKey)` checks that all the required signatures are present and valid, except for those listed as `allowedToBeMissing`. It does **not** check whether the transaction is valid according to the contracts of its states.

This function is useful is you know that one or more required signatures have not yet been added (e.g. if you are a required signer, but you want to check the existing signatures before adding your own).